# Reactjs with Flux: when and where to initialize a Timer utility in a Flux application

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I have three different things going on in my application:

1. A Timer is set at 10 second intervals and does't stop until asked to
2. An async Api Utility module triggers a function to call an Api once the timer starts over again.
3. I have a Component (w/ accompanying Action and Store modules) that takes the api data (a list of similar items with the same Properties) and renders them to the page.

My question is this:

> Where and When do I initialize the timer to being so that my Component can start receiving data after its `render()` method is invoked?

---

I've considered putting it inside the `render` function before the return is reached but that doesn't make sense as I need the api data rendered to the page as soon as the data is received.

Am I structuring this application incorrectly? should my Timer and/or Api utilities be React Components too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure there are a few ways to it, but here is my 2 cents:

Lets assume you have LogViewer application and you want to fetch and display logs every 10 seconds.

- Then you would have a `LogStore` and a `LogViewer` component.
- In the `componentDidMount` method of the `LogViewer` component, I would call `LogStore.getLogs()`.
- `LogStore.getLogs()` would call `APIUtils.getLogs()` and setup a timer to be fired every 10 seconds which calls `APIUtils.getLogs()` every time it is fired. After setting the timer `LogStore.getLogs()` immediately returns an empty array.
- The empty array is rendered by the `LogViewer` component (or a loading bar is shown).
- Meanwhile, the ajax call from `APIUtils.getLogs()` returns and `GET_LOGS_SUCCESS` server action is dispatched to all stores.
- `LogStore` saves the incoming logs and emits a change event for the `LogViewer` component to call `LogStore.getLogs()` function again.
- If at some point you want to stop the timer, then in the `LogViewer` component I would have a stop button which in turn creates `GET_LOGS_STOP` action when clicked.
- When `GET_LOGS_STOP` action is dispatched to the `LogStore`, it would react by stoping the timer.

I think that would fulfill your requirements.

Comment: This really helps. It hadn't occurred to me to return empty data before the async call was done in order to get things going in the UI. Where would be the most appropriate place to dispatch the GET_LOGS_SUCCESS from, as APIUtils naturally doesn't have an accompanying APIActions module?

Comment: You can have a `ServerActionCreator` (or `APIActionCreator`) class and call `ServerActionCreator.receiveGetLogs` from the `success` callback of your ajax function in the `APIUtils.getLogs()`. Then `ServerActionCreator.receiveGetLogs` would dispatch the `GET_LOGS_SUCCESS` action to the dispatcher.

Comment: Thanks again for your input; with it, I was able to sanely get a start on this project.